# Python Regular Expression getting sub string

Tags: python, regex

`card_travel2 - 3 yrslocation_onKolkata`

From above string I want to get 2 - 3 yrs which regular expression can I use?

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are looking something like this,

```
import re
pattern = r'\d+\s+-\s+\d+\s+yrs'
text = 'card_travel2 - 3 yrslocation_onKolkata'
re.findall(pattern, text)
```

output

```
['2 - 3 yrs']
```

Comment: ['2 - 3 yrs'] can you please tell me how i can remove the brackets and quotes also? I need 2 - 3 yrs only..

Comment: `re.findall(pattern, text)[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now last one  Aryan technologies (More Jobs) in this string i want only name of organization. means i want to remove (more jobs) part.

Comment: simply use the string replace method, eg: `inp_str.replace('(more jobs)','')`

Comment: not working.. It is giving me same string

Comment: `inp_str.replace('(More Jobs)','')` Its case sensitive

Comment: card_travel0 - 3 yrs₹Rs 1.00 - 3.00 Lacs p.a. how to select 1.00 - 3.00 Lacs form this string?

Comment: Use pattern `pattern = r'\d+.\d+\s+-\s+\d+.\d+\s+Lacs`

Comment: hello can you please help me with another pattern, I want to convert 1.20 - 2.70 LPA to 120000 - 270000 please help.